# Eclipse does not resolve .../tools or ../res-auto

Tags: android, eclipse-plugin, adt

i am  trying to implement something in android, but my eclipse does not recognize:

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

When i try to use:
app:headerLayout....
i get:  No resource identifier found for attribute 'headerLayout'

My complete XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start" >

    <include
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main" >
    </include>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/acitivity_main_drawer"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I´am using API 23.

Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `com.android.support:design:23.0.0` as a dependency or some other version of it.

Your gradle dependency should look something like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'
}
```

In case of Eclipse:

1. Open your `Android SDK Manager`, and download `Extras > Android Support Library`.
2. Once that's done, in your SDK location, go to the path: `sdk\extras\android\support\design`
3. You will find the android design library project that. Import that into Eclipse workspace and add this as a 'library' dependency to your main project.

Comment: hey, thx, i know about this, but i like i said above, i am using eclipse, and i dont know, how can i solve this on onclise

Comment: @RomaKap I have updated my answer for Eclipse scenario.